# Collision sensor triggering when property is near?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

After trying to figure out [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38403/collision-sensor-triggering-without-collision) problem, and being told to turn on physics visualization, I noticed the issue with the old problem. When a property is *near* my object, the sensor gets triggered. If it collides with it, it works as expected. When near (, with physics visualization on), I could see a yellow cylinder shape connecting the two objects and the sensor triggers. I was originally looking to make this work by collision *and only* collision, but it also triggers when near the property, *but it still doesn't touch!* How can I keep the sensor triggering only when the property on another object touches the original object, but not when it is near? Thanks!

**EDIT**: Ah! I went in to the [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38250) when I've had time, I've figured out that the problem is the collision type! The "sensor" physics type collides with other materials/proprties not when they collide, but when they are *near*. Here, take a look! I have a .gif [here](http://recordit.co/0S0pNGjUIA).

Comment: @X-27 its a collision sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the collision bound margins for *both* objects to the *lowest*.